# Achievements view in iOS app doesn't mark badges as "read"

Tags: feature-request, badges, ios-app, achievements-dialog

New achievements have a blue background, both reputation and badges. This helps differentiate them from ones you've already seen.

But badges don't clear that highlighting until you view them on the desktop. Can we clear them at the same time as reputation?

> [image]

<sub>Highlighting is Photoshopped since I forgot to take a screenshot. Color may be slightly off</sub>

Comment: beautiful photoshopping on the bottom